# C# Dynamic TValue in Dictionary

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

This question may be a bit of a long shot however please read on:

I have a set of stored procedures that are run and all of their data is stored in dictionarys.

For example getEventTypes is stored in the eventTypeResult dictionary and the getEventCats is stored in the dictonary eventCatResult.

Is it possible to run the following line dynamicly:

```
Dictionary<string, eventTypeResult> resultsList = (Dictionary<string, eventTypeResult>)resultsObject;
```

Where is could look something like this:

```
var resultType = eventTypeResult;

Dictionary<string, resultType > resultsList = (Dictionary<string, resultType >)resultsObject;
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Attempt 2 at explaining why it needs to be dynamic

Currently my code looks like this:

```
if (resultType == "eventTypeResult")
{
    Dictionary<string, eventTypeResult> resultsList = (Dictionary<string, eventTypeResult>)resultsObject;
}
else if (resultType == "eventDateResult")
{
    Dictionary<string, eventDateResult> resultsList = (Dictionary<string, eventDateResult>)resultsObject;
}
else if
else if
else if
ect
ect
```

Could it not just be like this:

```
var resultType = eventTypeResult;

Dictionary<string, resultType > resultsList = (Dictionary<string, resultType >)resultsObject;
```

Comment: what do you mean dynamically? whats the problem with it the way it is?

Comment: Sorry its very hard to explain this. See my edit :) Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, typing cannot be done in this way. You already see as much when you try `var resultType = eventTypeResult;` as that will give you `'eventTypeResult' is a 'type' but is used as a 'variable'` error. The best solution depends on your end goal: Are you looking for something repackageable to other cases? Are you looking to consolidate code, will be performing the same operations on the results, and `eventTypeResult` and `eventDateResult` have similar signatures? Or, do you need to handle each case pretty much exclusively, depending on type?

Answer (score 1):

"Dynamic" is probably not the best approach in a strongly typed language...
What you are trying to create is an arbitrary name value collection, like the various cache types in the .Net Framework. you need to relay on a common type, that can hold all of your result types.

if you have such a type something like  `resultType` that all the rest of the result Types inherit from, then use it: `Dictionary<string, resultType >` . you can put what ever you want in the value as long as it is a **sub class** of `resultType`. If you dont then use `Dictionary<string, object >`

if you need to cast between Dictioneries you can always (the object acutal type must match):

```
var thing = new Dictionery<int> ()
var objectThing = thing.Cast<Dictionery<object>();
```

if you want dynamic you can:

```
Dictionary<string, resultType > dict;
dyamic value = dict["something"];
value.WhaterverYouWant() // if this method doesnt exist this will compile but crash at runtime...
```

Comment: Your answer resolve the issue but you didn't considered boxing when we use `object` in Dictionary TValue this increase the GC pressure and impact our performance. Have you any other approach to resolve this?